# java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation: (SpringSecurityCoreGrailsPlugin.groovy:133)

Tags: java, grails, compilation, spring-security

I just check out a project and I was trying to run it and it won't. There's an error causing this that says:

```
java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 

at SpringSecurityCoreGrailsPlugin$_closure1.doCall(SpringSecurityCoreGrailsPlugin.groovy:133)
at _GrailsPackage_groovy$_run_closure5_closure19.doCall(_GrailsPackage_groovy:234)
at _GrailsPackage_groovy$_run_closure5_closure19.doCall(_GrailsPackage_groovy)
at _GrailsSettings_groovy$_run_closure10.doCall(_GrailsSettings_groovy:280)
at _GrailsSettings_groovy$_run_closure10.call(_GrailsSettings_groovy)
at _GrailsPackage_groovy$_run_closure5.doCall(_GrailsPackage_groovy:232)
at _GrailsPackage_groovy$_run_closure2.doCall(_GrailsPackage_groovy:168)
at RunApp$_run_closure1.doCall(RunApp.groovy:28)
at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:381)
at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)
at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy)
at gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427)
at gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)
at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
at gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415)
at gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)
at gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)
at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590)
at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:589)
Error executing script RunApp: Unresolved compilation problem:
```

solutions tried:
Since I am not sure what is causing this, I just checked out the project and did not modify anything.
I just tried to project>clean, grails-clean, grails-compile, project>refresh multiple times. I double checked the plugin and it is in the project installed already.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post more info about this app? eg. Grails version, Plugin version. You tried use refresh-dependencies?

Comment: The wording of your question suggests you're running in Eclipse/STS - does it work if you do `grails clean` and `grails run-app` from the command line instead of in Eclipse?

Comment: @Sergio refresh dependencies fixed my prob. thanks. to ian, no grails-clean alone did not work as stated in my tried solutions. thanks for your help guys :)